# How to restrict 2 portal users from seeing each others contact when they both belong to a same account in Salesforce

Tags: community, partner-communities

I have a situation where there are 2 portal users who belong to the same account and hence they are able to see each others contact information through their portal login. I do not want them to see each others contact information. By default all contacts belonging to the same account are being shared with each other. Is there a solution or workaround for this situation.

Comment: Which type of portal/community is this and what type of users are they? The solution can be different if they are partner community, customer community or customer community plus licences or the old portal licences.

Comment: @Dave Humm User License type is "Partner Community"

Comment: is OWD for external user private, otherwise try it

Comment: @Rahul Sharma Both Internal and External Access for Contact is set to Private in OWD

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but if they shouldn't see each other's contact info, are they really belonging to the same account? Can't you put them in 2 separate accounts? If there's data in the Contact object that they shouldn't see of each other, you might want to consider storing that in a 'real' private custom object..

Comment: @Guy I too had the same thought and suggested client but they does not want to place them in two different accounts.

Comment: Since Users and Contacts are tightly interwoven in the Partner Community, you might try out the 'Community User Visibility' option explained here. If you hide the Users, it might affect the Contacts as well..: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_sharing_owd_external_user_settings.htm&language=en_US